# Is there any way to get v-model value in computed property?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have retrieved the value from the database. I want to calculate the the data before render and show in the modal (regarding that user). How I can calculate the data for each and every user and show in the modal? I used to calculate the data in v-model like 'v-model="2 * item.amount * 0.09"'. But problem is I can't calculate summation. It is concatenate. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4XKp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a watcher on item.amount and calculate the amount you want to show in your modal? Or just use a computed to get the right amount

Comment: Thank you. I have used watcher.